# PHP include no longer working with non standard file type

Tags: php, include

I'm setting up a new web server with CentOS 7.4. My old server uses CentOS 6.
Several webpages use php include with arbitrary file extensions.

This still works:

```
include '../../includes/header.php';
```

This no longer works:

```
include 'nav.inc';
```

PHP version is -5.4.16-46.el7
There is nothing in the error_log.

Can someone help with what I need to configure in php.ini or the httpd.conf file?

Thanks

Comment: Try require() instead of include. Perhaps include is failing and errors are not being shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had set short_open_tag = On in php.ini, but for some reason it was still set to off. Setting it back to On fixed the problem.

Comment: The reason is that `shot_open_tag` is set to `off` by default to prevent conflicts with other embedded languages, templates or just typos. Code should be refactored sooner or later. That's not that much work with a full featured IDE.

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope it will help:
use php extension too like :nav.inc.php

```
include_once('nav.inc.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your include path in `php.ini`. The default is `include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"`, first looking into the current work directory `.`, then further directories of shared libraries.

If you cannot or do not want to administrate the system settings, you can use the `set_include_path` or `ini_set` function from within PHP as well or a `php.ini` on directory basis or `php_value` in `.htaccess`.